# C# create multiple images and save them

Tags: c#, loops, save

I want to create multiple 200x200 images with a number centered on them and save them with the corresponding file name automatically to a folder. Just that, nothing more.

I figured it'd be best to try this with an imagebox and writing on it with a loop, but I'm getting nowhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, bud. However; to accomplish what you want, you'll need to call the 'Graphics' class, available in the **System.Drawing** namespace.

The task you want done is quite easy.

First loop through the images you wanna create

Lets say you want 5 images

... call the for loop!

```
for (int I = 0; I < 5; I++) { }
```

Inside the loop we want to create a 200x200 image which is available to edit.
I prefer the 'Bitmap' class to accomplish this.

After creating the Bitmap, I'll create Graphics for it.
Then I will draw the string in approx. the center. If you want the 100% center, you can use the MeasureString function

Final code:

```
for (int I = 0; I < 5; I++) {
    Bitmap B = new Bitmap(200, 200);
    Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(B);
    G.DrawString(I.ToString(), this.Font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(100.0f, 100.0f);
    B.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolders.Desktop), I + ".png"))) // Save on the desktop
}
```

**I haven't tried this code yet, but I assume it works. Few modifications may be needed :)**

Comment: This won't position the text in the dead center, but start drawing it from the center. So a `StringFormat` or something to position it in dead center would be needed as stated. Just pointing it more out :)

Comment: Thanks as well but.. `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawString(string, System.Drawing.Font, System.Drawing.Brush, System.Drawing.RectangleF)' has some invalid arguments`, `cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'`, `cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Point' to 'System.Drawing.RectangleF'`.. all on line G.DrawString

Comment: Two Seconds. I will fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry only got my phone...

In pseudo code

Create a loop.

```
Inside the loop create a bitmap
    // for i=0...
    // using (var BMP = new bitmap(dimensions))
    {
    // get graphics 
       Using (graphics g = graphics.fromimage(BMP))
    {
    // draw text
    Text render.draw text()
    // save image
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be as simple as having a method doing the hard work:

```
public void CreateImageWithText(string text)
{
    using (var b = new Bitmap(200, 200))
    {
        using (var g = new Graphics.FromImage(b))
        {
            using (var f = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point))
            {
                var strFormat = new StringFormat();
                strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                strFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

                g.DrawString(text, f, Brushes.Blue, new Rectangle(0,0,200,200), strFormat);
            }
        }
        b.Save("C:\\image.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

And then in a for loop doing:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    CreateImageWithText(string.Format("{0}", i));
```

Remember to dispose correctly of your `Bitmap`s, `Graphics` and `Font` instances if you plan on calling it a lot of times. This is what the using statements in my methods are for.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting two errors here.. "The name 'ImageFormat' does not exist in the current context" and "'System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(System.Drawing.Image)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'".

Comment: Looks like I had to specify System.Drawing.Imaging specifically.. however, I still can't get rid of the second error.. `'System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(System.Drawing.Image)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'`.

Comment: I combined bits of this with @dotTutorials', works now :) Thanks again!